# Show only "Request exceeded the limit" errors in error.log

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

How can I show only "Request exceeded the limit" entries in error.log?  I looked at find and similar functions, I figure I'll need to use grep.  But I'm missing a piece of the puzzle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
grep 'Request exceeded the limit' /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Comment: I enabled `LogLevel debug` in an effort to debug that error, but it doesn't appear to show up in error.log at all.... any ideas on what else I should look for?

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding what you are wanting to do. If your error log contains any "Request exceeded the limit" messages, the command I provided will display them. Are you simply trying to ensure that Apache logs any requests that generate a "Request exceeded the limit" error or something else?

Comment: I get this error all the time in our logs.  When I enable `Loglevel Debug` it seems to no longer log these messages.  I can't tell because of all the SSL stuff that's logged